# Creating a DataFrame from namedtuples that contain dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

Given a `list` of `namedtuples`, does anyone know how to create a pandas `DataFrame` from selected columns of which some contain dictionaries that I want to treat as columns? If you simply call `pandas.DataFrame()` the dictionaries will not be "expanded", so you have to create another `DataFrame` from them, and append the columns you want to the original DataFrame. This strikes me as inelegant and inefficient; can it be done in one line?

```
import pandas, collections
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y', 'val'])
p1 = Point(1,2,{'name':'foo', 'age':12})
p2 = Point(3,4,{'name':'bar', 'age':24})
pandas.DataFrame([p1, p2])

   0  1                           2
0  1  2  {'age': 12, 'name': 'foo'}
1  3  4  {'age': 24, 'name': 'bar'}
```

Comment: Can you give an reproducible example of the namedtuple you have this issue with?

Comment: I don't think you can do anything about that. Easy way to expand them: `df[2].apply(pd.Series)`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `pandas.concat` and `DataFrame.apply` as *joris* proposed in the comment:

```
import pandas, collections
Point = collections.namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y', 'val'])
p1 = Point(1,2,{'name':'foo', 'age':12})
p2 = Point(3,4,{'name':'bar', 'age':24})
df = pandas.DataFrame([p1, p2])
print pandas.concat([df.iloc[:,:2],df[2].apply(pandas.Series)],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  age name
0  1  2   12  foo
1  3  4   24  bar
```